# InfoBubble reposition according to viewport in Here Maps 3.1 Version

Tags: javascript, here-api

the infobubbles re-position in the viewport so they stay on the screen (e.g. if it's on the top of the viewport, then the infobubble re-positions to the bottom so it doesn't appear off screen)

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I'm not sure to understand what you are asking.

Comment: there's no such option in the latest API version.

Comment: @Gabriel Glenn     The infobubble gets cut when the truck is on top/bottom or on any corner of the maps viewport. In this case, infoBubble sets position according to maps viewport.Need suggestions on how to reposition the infobubble in this scenario.

Comment: @Tomas Sorry for the delay in response. Thanks for your answer.